# Habilitar Campo de uma determinada linha de tabela através de um botão com JQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou com dúvida para esse sistema em **Jquery**,

A ideia é quando clicar em **EDITAR** em uma determinada linha, ative somente os `inputs` daquela determinada linha do edit clicado.

Há também dois Privilégio de Edição, **ADM** e **NORMAL**, o **NORMAL** deve somente editar a coluna **NOME**, o **ADM** as colunas **NOME** e **SALARIO**; isso eu consegui.

```js
var op = "";
     var privilegio = "";

     function acesso(op){
      privilegio = op;
     }


     function edit(){
      if(privilegio == 'adm'){
       $(this).parent().next().find('.salario').removeAttr('disabled');
       $(this).parent().next().find('.nome').removeAttr('disabled');
       
      }
      else{
       $('table').find('.nome').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
      
     }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Desafio</title>
  <script src="http://localhost/2015-3/tratamentoevalidacao/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <input onclick="acesso('adm')" name="privilegio" type="radio" value="adm">Adm 
  <input onclick="acesso('normal')" name="privilegio" checked type="radio" value="normal">Normal

  <table border="1">
   <tr><td>Operações</td><td>Nome</td><td>Salário</td></tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit('editar')" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir()" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled  class="nome" type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled class="salario"  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   
   

   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>

  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

abaixo a resolução do problema:

```js
     var op = "";
     var privilegio = "";
     var excluindo = 0;

     function acesso(op){
      privilegio = op;
     }


     function edit(edit){
      if(privilegio == 'adm'){
       $(edit).parent().next().find('input').prop("disabled", false);
       $(edit).parent().next().next().find('input').prop("disabled", false);   
      }
      else{
       $(edit).parent().next().find('input').prop("disabled", false); 
      }

      $(edit).parent().html('<input type="button" onclick="confirmar(this)" value="Confirmar">'); 
     }

     function confirmar(conf){
      if(excluindo == 1){
       excluindo = 0;
       $(conf).parent().next().find('input').val('');
       $(conf).parent().next().next().find('input').val('');
      }
      $(conf).parent().next().find('input').prop("disabled", true);
      $(conf).parent().next().next().find('input').prop("disabled", true);
      $(conf).parent().html('<input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir">');

     }

     function excluir(excluir){
      excluindo = 1;
      if(privilegio == 'adm'){
       $(excluir).parent().next().find('input').prop("disabled", false);
       $(excluir).parent().next().next().find('input').prop("disabled", false);   
      }
      else{
       $(excluir).parent().next().find('input').prop("disabled", false); 
      }
      $(excluir).parent().html('<input type="button" onclick="confirmar(this)" value="Confirmar">'); 
     }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Desafio</title>
  <script src="http://localhost/2015-3/tratamentoevalidacao/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <input onclick="acesso('adm')" name="privilegio" type="radio" value="adm">Adm 
  <input onclick="acesso('normal')" name="privilegio" checked type="radio" value="normal">Normal

  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td>Operações</td>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Salário</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td class="salario"><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td><td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input class="edit" type="button" onclick="edit(this)" value="Edit"><input class="excluir" type="button" onclick="excluir(this)" value="Excluir"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="text" name="nome"></td>
    <td><input disabled  type="text" name="salario"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```